# Using XPath to parse XML from web, passing to HTML form

Tags: java, html, xml, xpath

I have having difficulty making an XPath script run. I am using DocumentBuilderFactory to store XML data from another website on the server. My logic and syntax look correct to me, but the script will not run.

Here is a link to the full HTML:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3u429bn5bjd4i9/orecalculator.txt

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    URL url = new URL("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=22,17425,17426,1223,17428,17429,1225,17432,17433,1232,17436,17437,1229,17865,17866,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1226,17448,17449,20,17452,17453,11396,17869,17870,1227,17867,17868,18,17455,17456,1224,17459,17460,1228,17463,17464,19,17466,17467,1230,17470,17471&regionlimit=10000002");
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(url.openStream());
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

var IDs = [22,17425,17426,1223,17428,17429,1225,17432,17433,1232,17436,17437,1229,17865,17866,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1226,17448,17449,20,17452,17453,11396,17869,17870,1227,17867,17868,18,17455,17456,1224,17459,17460,1228,17463,17464,19,17466,17467,1230,17470,17471];

calculate = function (i)
{
    var y = document.getElementById('reward'); //to display in reward box
    var x = 0;  
    XPathExpression expr;
    Object result;
    var elm;
    while (i + 1 < IDs.length)
    {
        expr = xpath.compile("//marketstat/type[@id = '" + IDs[i] + "']/buy/max/text()"); //define XPath for each typeID
        result = expr.evaluate(document);
        elm = document.getElementById(IDs[i]);
        x=x+parseInt(elm.value||0)*parseInt(result); //multiply the max buy price for this typeID by the number of units entered in the html form
        i++;
    }
    y.value = x;
};

</script>
```

The script's purpose is to multiply the user's inputs for each form by the associated "max buy" for that item's ID from the eve-central XML. It is supposed to behave like this Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iLxDHFQOfAsiFPSUr0bU1sXyE37dfUdVAXc1xoSzFCc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just put Java inside Javascript `script` tags inside an HTML page and expect it to run.
For this to work, you have to either rewrite your code in Javascript, or create a full-fledged Java web application.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering why Javascript in script tags had slightly different syntax than what I was used to from full-fledged java. I will try one of those options.